# Adding autoplay to jQuery tab box

Tags: jquery, tabs

Im looking to add an autoplay function to the following  jquery tabbed content (is just below the fold on the hyperlink)

http://www.efftel.co.uk/index-test.html

Ideally want the content tabs to scroll through intermittently and then pause when you hover over the area. Not really sure how to do it. The site is using jquery so I'm hoping there's a simple way to do it using that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using slick.js carousel and in order to autoplay the content you should set the autoplay setting to true:
$('.autoplay').slick({
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});

Also you can specify the autoplaySpeed value and slidesToScroll.

Comment: i actually mean the orange tabbed box that is just beneath 'How We Can Help Your Business' H3 tag. That's a jquery tabbed content box.